# How can I save a local file into assets folder in Flutter

Tags: flutter, file, flutter-windows

My flutter desktop application takes a local file (audio/video/image) as user input. Now I need to save it to somewhere for later usage. So that even if the device changes the application can still access them using relative path.

What I want to do is copy this file to *assets* folder using `file.copy` method. But how can I get the assets folder's directory? I don't want to hardcode assets folder's absolute path. Is there any way to copy files into assets folder using relative path?

Or any alternate way to do the task?

Answer (score 5):

`assets` is read-only. Use documents directory where the application can store files that only it can access.

```
final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
```

See [Read and write files](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files) for details.

Comment: If I give the absolute path to copy in assets folder, it works. If assets is read-only, then why it works with absolute path?